# sAMAccountName searching in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I am quite new with VB, so I want to ask you for help. I want to add searching functionality to this code. Let´s say that someone will search for sAMaccountname and he will get back email by this user. I really don´t know how to work with attributes in AD, so only what i have is this (I think it is really easy to find what will be result :) ). When I will see how to do it for samaccountname to email, I think I can continue with other things also. Thank you.

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim domains As DomainCollection = Forest.GetCurrentForest.Domains
        For Each domain As Domain In domains
            'MessageBox.Show(domain.Name)
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(domain.Name)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim domain As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ourdomain.com/OU=Users,OU=Czech Republic,OU=TEAD,DC=eu,DC=ourcompany,DC=com")
        For Each child As DirectoryEntry In domain.Children
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(child.Name)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
Public Shared Function FindEmailsFromSamAccountName(ByVal samAccountName As String) As String

    Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)

    Dim qbeUser As New UserPrincipal(ctx)
    qbeUser.SamAccountName = samAccountName
    qbeUser.Enabled = True

    Dim srch As New PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser)
    For Each foundUser In srch.FindAll
        Dim up As UserPrincipal = CType(foundUser, UserPrincipal)
        Return up.EmailAddress
    Next
    Return ""
End Function
```

It just returns the first one it finds. You should add some error checking in here.

You can expand the search to return more matches by adding "*" at the start or end of the `samAccountName` to give a wildcard search.

Comment: Fantastic, working exactly as I need, thank you :) just more question to this, if we are using more AD domains, how to get results from all of them?